# Unicode doesn't work correct in Debian Stretch

Tags: unicode, utf-8, debian, locale

I have a problem with some unicode symbols, such as "U+1F5D8".
When I visit https://unicode-table.com/en/1F5D8/ in Chrome or Firefox I see [square with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI0MZ.png) ("Your browser" section).

I'm using Debian Stretch (stable). I think it might be important, because everything is working fine on my Buster (testing) machine.

```
root@storm:/# gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.22.3
root@storm:/# uname -r
4.9.0-4-amd64
root@storm:/# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The "ttf-mscorefonts-installer" package is already installed

What can I do make unicode symbols display correctly?

Comment: In my Firefox I cannot see asian characters :|
For example in Google Translation Website.
My Firefox installation is downloaded from theirs website